# Flutter: iOS Style navigation/transition

Tags: dart, flutter

What's the closest way to simulate iOS style navigations in Flutter, more specifically the Present Modally kind with the Over Full-Screen presentation and the Cross Dissolve transition? I tried looking at their docs and the constructor page but it was of no help.

[image]

CODE:

```
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
            onPressed: () {
              AnimationController controller = new AnimationController(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200), vsync: this);
              Animation<double> animation = new Tween(begin: 0.1, end: 1.0).animate(controller);

              CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition(
                animation: animation,
                child: Container(color: Colors.blue, width: 100.0, height: 100.0,),
              );
            },
          ),
```

But he does nothing. I even tried

```
Animation<double> animation = new Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 300.0).animate(controller);
```

and that does nothing as well.

Comment: Ever find an answer for this?